# No response from google sign in

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-signin

I'm the following the following link to integrate Google login into my ASP.NET application:  https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

Here's the code snippet:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <title></title>
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="**REDACTED**">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
    <script>
        function onSignIn(googleUser) {
            // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
            var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
            console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
            console.log("Name: " + profile.getName());
            console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
            console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

            // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
            var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
            console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
        };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I click the sign in button, I get the permissions page. But the console log is empty when I click on allow. Although, clearly from the code it should fill the log in name, id, email.  What am I missing here? Please help

Comment: I have a similar issue, except I'm building a PHP app. What's interesting is I found that on the consent screen, it says _Clicking "Allow" will redirect you to:
storagerelay://https/<domain>?id=<authid>"_

Answer (score 1):

If the onsuccess callback isn't being hit most like your signin is not succeeding. Verify by adding an onfailure callback.

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-onfailure="onFailure" data-theme="dark"></div>
<script>
    function onFailure() { console.error('Sign in has failed!'); }
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        console.log("Name: " + profile.getName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: I did that as well.  onFailure is not being hit as well.
I get the request for permission page and I click "Allow" and nothing.

Comment: Although, my apps shows in "Apps connected to your account".

Comment: @MAK were you able to solve it?